# SQLite3 RECURSIVE WITH UPDATE with AGGREGATE

Tags: recursion, sqlite, average

Have read and tried to take in previous discussion on this subject without enlightenment. SQL Code below has imbedded comments.
SQLite version 3.9.1 2015-10-16 17:31:12 on Windows 7
The subquery subordinate to the SET clause in the UPDATE does not recurse - delivers a single scalar value. Or am I having a recursion meltdown?

```
// In which we investigate recursive update
.mode list
SELECT 'Create and populate tables of detail and to hold aggregate';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp.detail;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp.average;
CREATE TEMP TABLE detail  (rowid INTEGER PRIMARY Key AUTOINCREMENT, 
   grp INTEGER,atom FLOAT);
INSERT INTO detail (grp,atom) VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO detail (grp,atom) VALUES (2,4);
INSERT INTO detail (grp,atom) VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO detail (grp,atom) VALUES (1,5);
INSERT INTO detail (grp,atom) VALUES (3,1);
INSERT INTO detail (grp,atom) VALUES (3,3);
SELECT * FROM detail;
CREATE TEMP TABLE average (rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, avrg FLOAT);
INSERT INTO average (avrg) VALUES (1.0);
INSERT INTO average (avrg) VALUES (1.0);
INSERT INTO average (avrg) VALUES (1.0);
.mode column average
.mode column detail
.header on
.width 7
SELECT avrg as Average FROM average;
SELECT 'SELECT produces three rows';
with recursive loop(bid) as (Values(1) union all
    select bid + 1 from loop LIMIT 3)
    SELECT AVG(atom) AS Average  from detail 
    where grp IN loop GROUP BY grp;

Average
-------
4.0
3.0
2.0
```

```
SELECT 'Within SET clause, SELECT produces one scalar result';
with recursive loop(bid) as (Values(1) union all
    select bid + 1 from loop LIMIT 3)
    UPDATE average SET avrg =
    (SELECT AVG(atom) from detail
    WHERE grp in loop GROUP BY grp HAVING grp IN loop)
    where rowid in loop;
SELECT 'Single SET result populates all target rows';
SELECT avrg AS Average from average;

Average
-------
4.0
4.0
4.0
```

OK, a day later, so I've tried to correlate the loop control table into the subquery.

```
with recursive loop(grp) as (Values(1) union all
select grp + 1 from loop LIMIT 3)
UPDATE average SET avrg =
(SELECT AVG(atom) from detail, loop
WHERE detail.grp = loop.grp 
GROUP BY detail.grp)
where rowid IN loop;
SELECT avrg AS Average FROM average;
```

### Average

4.0
4.0
4.0 
Or I tried this...

```
    sqlite> with recursive loop(grp) as (Values(1) union all
   ...>     select grp + 1 from loop LIMIT 3)
   ...>     UPDATE average SET avrg =
   ...>     (SELECT AVG(atom) from detail, loop
   ...>     GROUP BY loop.grp)
   ...>     where rowid IN loop;
   sqlite> SELECT avrg AS Average FROM average;
```

### Average

3.0
3.0
3.0
Which is different but still undesired. 
What I require is behaviour like that from the INSERT variant...

```
sqlite> DROP TABLE average;
sqlite> CREATE TEMP TABLE average (rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
avrg FLOAT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO average (avrg)
...>     with recursive loop(grp) as (Values(1) union all
...>     select grp + 1 from loop LIMIT 3)
...>     SELECT AVG(atom) from detail NATURAL JOIN loop
...>     GROUP BY grp;
sqlite> SELECT avrg AS Average FROM average;
```

### Average

4.0
3.0
2.0

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: This has nothing to do with recursion; the problem is that the subquery is not correlated.